# Different results with BSplineSurface and BSplineFunction

Tags: splines

There seems to be some differences when plotting a surface with `BSplineSurface` and with `BSplineFunction`.

```
Points={...}

A=BSplineSurface[Points]
B=BSplineFunction[Points]

PlotA=Graphics3D[A]
PlotB=ParametricPlot3D[B[u,v],{u,0,1},{v,0,1}]
```

Notice the ripples when using `BSplineFunction` (Second image below). Results from 'BSplineSurface' seems much more "natural".

[image: BSplineSurface]
[image: BSplineFunction]

Any ideas on how to make results from `BSplineFunction` look like the ones from `BSplineSurface`?

Comment: They're supposed to give equivalent results. Try to increase the `PlotPoints` setting of `ParametricPlot3D[]`.

Comment: @J. M. You are right. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @J.M.isback says, increasing the number of `PlotPoints` in `ParametricPlot3D` solves the problem.